# Solving a Calculus velocity question using Precalc.

Tags: calculus

Decide whether on not Calculus is needed for the problem. If it is, use Pre-Calculus to approximate an answer. Find the distance traveled in 10 seconds by an object traveling at a velocity of v(t) = 20 + 7cos(t) feet per second. I know that Calculus is needed as the velocity is not constant, I'm just unsure how to approach the problem.

Comment: How about starting with integrating to get the position as a function of time?

Comment: We aren't supposed to; the idea is to use Pre Calc math to approximate the distance.

Comment: So if Calculus is needed, you have to use pre-Calc to approximate?

Comment: That's the idea- it's kind of an introduction to limits and rate of change.

Comment: Ok. So numerically approximate the "accumulated area" of the velocity curve. Do you have a starting $t$-value?

Comment: It wasn't explicitly stated, but I think it's 0 since the unit of the t value is seconds.

Comment: So what's the difference between calc and pre-calc?

Comment: I would find the velocity for $t=1,2,\ldots, 10$. Then find the average distance traveled over each second (from $t=0$ to $t=1$, that would be $1\cdot v(1)$). Then estimate the total distance traveled as the sum of the average distances traveled. Of course, better estimates could be made by taking the time increments smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: integrate:$\;d(t) = \int v(t)\,dt$

where $d(t)$ gives the distance traveled in $t$ seconds.

If you cannot use integration, graph the curve, $v(t)$ and try to approximate the area under the curve. Note that when $t = 0$, $v(0) = 20 + 7\cos(0) = 27$ feet per second ($27$ is where the curve intersects the y-axis.) Perhaps calculate area given using one-second intervals.

See, for example, the graph below. The distance traveled in $t$ seconds (below, I've graphed from $t = 0$ to $t = 10$) is equal to the *area* bound by the curve $v(t)$ bound at the top, by $x = 0$ on the left, $x = 10$ on the right, and $y = 0$ (the x-axis) at the bottom. To approximate the area bound by this region, we can **sum** the area of narrow rectangles whose width is, say, $1$ unit, and whose height is $v(t)$ at $t = 1, 2, \ldots 10$.

[image]

Let me know if you'd like more details regarding how to do this!

Answer (score 4):

Without using calculus:

Separate $v(t)$ into two components, its constant component, and its cosine component.

From the constant component, it's easy to start by observing that a constant speed of 20 ft/sec for 10 sec yields 200ft. Hang onto this number.

From the cosine component, we know that cosine has a period of $2\pi$. At $t=2pi$, effect of the term has completely nullified itself: the amount of velocity above the $x$-axis has exactly the same profile as that below the $x$ axis. So let's look at $(2\pi,10)$.

Now, we know that $3\pi \approx 9.4 < 10$. From $2\pi$ to $3\pi$, we have the same effect: the velocity above the $x$ axis "neutralizes" the velocity below.

So now we're left with just a little tail of negative velocity between $3\pi$ and $10$. It's only about a half-second worth of time, and in that time the velocity goes from -7 to -5.87. Let's split the difference, and consider it to have a constant velocity in that half-second window of -6.43 ft/s. Multiplying this quantity by $(10-3\pi)$, and adding to the previous result, and we get about 196 feet.

---

Let's compare this to the integral:

$$\begin{align*}\int_0^10 \left(20+7\cos t\right)\ dt &= \left.20t\right|_0^10 + \left.7\sin t \right|_0^10 \\
 &= 200(10-0) + 7\sin(10)-7\sin(0) \\
 &= 200+7\sin(10) \\
 &= 200-3.808 \\
 &\approx 196.19.
\end{align*}$$